# JUnit Testing FaceContext and Session Code

Tags: java, intellij-idea, mockito, junit4, powermockito

I am attempting to Junit test (IDE: Intellij) Method inside a class called "ManagementDashboardBean" called: (Method name): init()
The method contains FaceContext and Session. I tried the following: https://codenotfound.com/mockito-unit-testing-facescontext-powermock-junit.html
but am still running into issues. I am using Mockito and PowerMockito to help but cannot figure out my init() is saying Null Pointer Exception (NPE). Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

P.S the end goal is to show proper test code coverage of this method.

```
   public void init() {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        HttpSession session = (HttpSession)context.getExternalContext().getSession(false);
        userInfo = (UserSessionInfo)session.getAttribute(ConstantsUtil.USER_INFO);

        startDt = FDUtil.toDate(FDUtil.toStartOfMonth(userInfo.getCurrentDateMillis()));
        endDt = FDUtil.toDate(FDUtil.toEndOfMonth(userInfo.getCurrentDateMillis()));

        autoCompleteDate = false;
    }
```

Current JUnit Test

```
package view.managed.core;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNull;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.context.ExternalContext;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import com.sun.jdi.connect.Connector;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.ArgumentCaptor;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({FacesContext.class})

public class ManagementDashboardBeanTest {

    private ManagementDashboardBean someBean;

    @Mock
    private FacesContext facesContext;
    @Mock
    private ExternalContext externalContext;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        someBean = new ManagementDashboardBean();

        //mock all static methods of FaceContext using PowerMockito
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(FacesContext.class);

        when(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()).thenReturn(facesContext);
        when(facesContext.getExternalContext()).thenReturn(externalContext);
    }

    @Test
    public void testInitContext() {
        //create Captor instances for the userInfo
//        ArgumentCaptor<String> clientIdCapture = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(String.class);
//        ArgumentCaptor<HttpSession> session = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(HttpSession.class);
        // Run the method being tested
//        someBean.init();

//        verify(facesContext).addMessage(clientIdCapture.capture(), (FacesMessage) session.capture());

    }

}
```

The actual .java source file starts with:

```
public class ManagementDashboardBean extends EntityManagerService implements Serializable {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ManagementDashboardBean.class);
```

The right after is this, which confuses the hell out of me:

```
public ManagementDashboardBean() {
        init();
    }
```

What I have added so far:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import mil.af.fd.view.managed.services.EntityManagerService;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import java.io.Serializable;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({FacesContext.class})

public class ManagementDashboardBeanTest {

    private ManagementDashboardBean dashboard;
    private Serializable serializableMock;
    private EntityManagerService entityManagerServiceMock;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void before() {
        System.out.println("Before Class");
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        entityManagerServiceMock = Mockito.mock(EntityManagerService.class);
        serializableMock = Mockito.mock(Serializable.class);
        dashboard = new ManagementDashboardBean(serializableMock);
    }

    @Test
    public void testInitContext() {
//          dashboard.init();
        System.out.println("Test 1");
    }

}
```

Comment: Where is the code that throws the `NullPointerException`? This version is mostly comments. Then, what line causes the null pointer? I don't see where you mock out `externalContext` to return a `session` but you call a method on the session.

Comment: I added the .java source code above. The ManagementDashboardBean contains an extends service; which I was going to use a Mockito mock for. Then the implements i as assuming would be a Mockito mock as well.

Comment: If the constructor calls `init()` you need to do all your mocking before you create the instance of `ManagementDashboardBean`.

Comment: Is there an easy way to determine all the mocks I would need to create? I attached the code I have so far for my JUnit test.

Comment: There isn't an easy way to determine what to mock. When you mock something you are determining what production code you are testing and what you are not. So you need to choose based on what gives you confidence your code is well tested. A reasonable pattern is to call your production code, when there is an error caused by a missing dependency, mock it and run your test again, repeat.

Comment: Also, not sure why you are mocking `Serializable` it is an interface with a constant. It's behavior can't really be mocked and doesn't need to be.

Comment: Thanks! So do all the private variables need to be mocked as well?